# Bug with expanding search bar

Tags: bug, status-norepro

After performing a search in the search bar the search terms remain in the bar.  If you click in the bar to change the search terms, the first character you type is inserted where you clicked but the cursor then moves to the end of the line and anything you type goes here instead.

Firefox 3.6.18 on Windows XP Pro SP3

Instructions to reproduce:

- Type search term 'break key'
- Hit Enter
- Page of results loads with 'break key' still in search box
- Click mouse in front of the 'b' in 'break' and start to type 'macbook'
- 'm' appears in front of 'break key' making 'mbreak key' and then the search box expands
- cursor moves to the end of the search string 'mbreak key' resulting in 'mbreak keyacbook'

Comment: any reason you're using a version of Firefox so old? They're up to Firefox 6 now..

Comment: Because my employer doesn't update their browsers very often. For what it's worth I can't reproduce in Chrome 13/Safari 5 on OS X.

Comment: If Firefox 3 is unsupported then fair enough, I'd understand that, just say so and I won't raise bugs for it again. I imagine there aren't many users still on it, people in my company are probably part of the unfortunate minority. IE6 is still their main supported browser!

Answer (score 1):

No repro in Chrome. What browser?

Can you provide exact repro steps, down to enumerating every click and keypress in the order that you performed them?

Also note that you can use the BIG ASS SEARCH BOX(tm) here:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know it's not a showstopper, but it's just unexpected behaviour I suppose